# Split ranges in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Given a list like:

```
[1, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]
```

Split it into blandly increasing ranges (maybe equal):

```
[[1, 2, 2], [6, 7, 8], [10, 11, 12], [15]]
```

I tried using a recursive approach:

```
splitRanges [] = [[]]
splitRanges (x:y:xs) 
  | x `elem` [y, y + 1] = [x, y] : splitRanges xs
  | otherwise = xs
```

So if the item is one less or equal to the item after I fuse them. But it says I am trying to build an infinite type:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
Expected type: [[a0]]
  Actual type: [a0]
```

> But what does [the fact that it is monotone] have to do with how the list is split?

That being strictly increasing would give different results.

> Or are you really trying to say something else?

I hope I am not.

> Will the list always be monotone?

No, splitting a monotone list means making it into just one sub-list.

> If not, how should that affect the results?

If it is not monotone, you will have many sublists.

> Is it always brown into groups of three?

No, the groups may contain n elements.

> More examples would be good

```
splitRanges [1, 3] == [[1], [3]]
splitRanges [1, 2, 5] == [[1, 2], [3]]
splitRanges [0, 0, 1] == [[0, 0, 1]]
splitRanges [1, 5, 7, 9] == [[1], [5], [7], [9]]
```

I appreciate hints rather than full answers, as I would like to improve myself, copy-pasting is not improvement.

Comment: hint: have a look at your `otherwise` case - do you really want just `xs` here? - btw: right now you can never get something like `[[a,b,c],..]` - because you only add lists with 2 elements in there

Comment: Since getting the last element of the list is costly, I'd keep the last seen range element as a function parameter and pass it around for comparison with the next coming element.

Comment: You can make a differential list first, then you can split the list while viewing only one element at a time.

Comment: I guess that a "blandly increasing range" is a list where every number is followed by itself or its successor (or the end of the list). Maybe you should define it more precisely (or is it standard, and I am unaware of that ?).

Comment: based on how much experience you have with this kind of stuff it should not be to hard to implement this using `foldr` - the first thing that comes to (my) mind is using a tuple of an *accumulator* list (to collect inner lists) and an result list of lists - as you are moving form the *right* you can use pattern matching on the head of the *accumulator*  to decide if you want to *keep accumulating* or if it is time to push and start a new *accumulator* - after the fold you need an additional step to *cons* the tuple ^^

Comment: @chi, maybe it's a local synonym for monotone? I don't really know. I also don't see how that actually relates to the way the list is being split.

Comment: @dfeuer yes. monotone, non-decreasing is more precise.

Comment: But what does that have to do with how the list is split? Or are you really trying to say something else? Will the list always be monotone? If not, how should that affect the results? Is it always brown into groups of three? A better verbal description and more examples would be good.

Comment: @dfeuer I hope I cleared out your doubts with my edit

Comment: @dfeuer No, "monotone" is weaker than what the OP wants.  It seems that each part must be of the form `[a..b]`, except with numbers possibly being repeated. As I wrote in my comment above, each number must be followed by itself or its successor (AFAICS). So perhaps it's "splitting in non-decreasing contiguous (maximal) parts".

Comment: @chi Exactly,you said it perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Try breaking the problem into more manageable parts.

First, how would you split just one blandly increasing range from the start of a list? Lets guess that should be `splitOne :: [Integer] -> ([Integer], [Integer])`.

Second, how can you repeatedly apply splitOne to the left-over list? Try implementing `splitMany :: [Integer] -> [[Integer]]` by using splitOne.

For splitOne, what should you be trying to find? The first position to split at. What are "split positions"? Lets make that up.

```
split    0     1      2      3      4      …
list  [  | x1, |  x2, |  x3, |  x4, |  x5, …]
```

So a split at 0 is `([], [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,…])`, and a split at 3 is `([x1,x2,x3],[x4,x5,…])`. What relationship can you see between the split position and the split list?

How do you determine the first split position of the list? Lets say that is implemented as `firstSplitPos :: [Integer] -> Integer`. What is the first split position of an empty list?

Can you now implement splitOne using firstSplitPos?

### One Possible Answer

---

```
-- What are the adjacencies for:
--   1) empty lists?
--   2) lists with one element?
--   3) lists with more than one element?
--
-- Bonus: rewrite in point-free form using <*>
--
adjacencies :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
adjacencies xxs = zip xxs (drop 1 xxs)

-- Bonus: rewrite in point-free form
--
withIndices :: [a] -> [(Int,a)]
withIndices xxs = zip [0..] xxs

-- This is the most involved part of the answer. Pay close
-- attention to:
--   1) empty lists
--   2) lists with one element
--   3) lists which are a blandly increasing sequence
--
firstSplitPos :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> Int
firstSplitPos xxs = maybe (length xxs) pos (find q searchList)
  where q (_,(a,b)) = a /= b && a + 1 /= b
        searchList  = withIndices (adjacencies xxs)
        -- Why is the split position one more than the index?
        pos (i,_)   = i + 1
--

-- Bonus: rewrite in point-free form using <*>
--
splitOne :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> ([a],[a])
splitOne xxs = splitAt (firstSplitPos xxs) xxs

splitMany :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> [[a]]
-- What happens if we remove the case for []?
splitMany []  = []
splitMany xxs = let (l, r) = splitOne xxs in l : splitMany r
```

### Another Approach

---

This is my explanation of [Carsten's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35369590/260584). It is already succinct but I have elected for a variation which does not use a 2-tuple.

We know that Haskell lists are defined inductively. To demonstrate this, we can define an equivalent data type.

```
data List a = Cons a (List a) -- Cons = (:)
            | Nil             -- Nil  = []
```

Then ask the question: can we use induction on lists for the solution? If so, we only have to solve two cases: Cons and Nil. The type signature of `foldr` shows us exactly that:

```
foldr ::     (a -> b -> b) -- Cons case
          -> b             -- Nil case
          -> [a]           -- The list 
          -> b             -- The result
```

What if the list is Nil? Then the only blandly increasing sequence is the empty sequence. Therefore:

```
nilCase = [[]]
```

We might want `nilCase = []` instead, as that also seems reasonable — i.e. there are no blandly increasing sequences.

Now you need some imagination. In the Cons case we only get to look at one new element at a time. With this new element, we could decide whether it belongs to the right-adjacent sequence or if it begins a new sequence.

What do I mean by right-adjacent? In `[5,4,1,2,2,7]`, `1` belongs to the right-adjacent sequence `[2,2]`.

How might this look?

```
-- The rest of the list is empty
consCase new []      = [new] : []

-- The right-adjacent sequence is empty
consCase new ([]:ss) = [new] : ss

-- The right-adjacent sequence is non-empty
-- Why `new + 1 == x` and not `new == x + 1`?
consCase new sss@(xxs@(x:_):ss)
  | new == x || new + 1 == x = (new:xxs):ss
  | otherwise                = [new]:sss
```

Now that we solved the Nil case and the Cons case, we are done!

```
splitRanges = foldr consCase nilCase
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you don't mind spoiling part of it, but as the comments are discussing what you want (and I hope I've got it) maybe you are interested in another possible solution?

I don't want to spoil it all but I think you can easily work this out:

```
blandly :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> [[a]]
blandly = g . foldr f ([],[])
  where f x ([],xss)       = ([x],xss)
        f x (y:ys,xss)
          | abs (x-y) <= 1 = undefined
          | otherwise      = undefined
        g (ys,xss)         = undefined
```

you just have to fill in the `undefined` holes

The idea is just to fold the list from the right, accumulating your inner lists in the first item of the tuple, s long as the elements are not to far away; and if they are: to push it to the second item.

If done correctly it will yield:

```
λ> blandly [1,3]
[[1],[3]]
λ> blandly [1,2,5]
[[1,2],[5]]
λ> blandly [0,0,1]
[[0,0,1]]
λ> blandly [1,5,7,9]
[[1],[5],[7],[9]]
```

which seems to be what you want

---

1 hour later - I think I can post *my* solution - just stop reading if you don't want to get spoiled

```
blandly :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> [[a]]
blandly = uncurry (:) . foldr f ([],[])
  where f x ([],xs) = ([x],xs)
        f x (y:ys,xs)
          | abs (x-y) <= 1 = (x:y:ys,xs)
          | otherwise     = ([x],(y:ys):xs)
```

maybe I have a slight misunderstanding here (the examples did not specify it) - but if you want on only monotonic increasing inner lists you just have to change the `abs` part:

```
blandly :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> [[a]]
blandly = uncurry (:) . foldr f ([],[])
  where f x ([],xss)    = ([x],xss)
        f x (y:ys,xss)
          | 0 <= y-x
            && y-x <= 1 = (x:y:ys,xss)
          | otherwise   = ([x],(y:ys):xss)
```

Comment: A bug in your solution, it creates decreasing sequences, the fix is ```x `elem` [y, y-1] = (x:y:ys,xs)``` . I have tried but not succeeded in writing it by myself but will analyze yours to learn in another way.

Comment: what do you mean by *decreasing sequences*? The examples are actual output from GHCi and seem to be what you expected above

Comment: or are you talking about that it will accept `5,4,3,...` also? I thought this is what you wanted - if not just remove the `abs (x-y)` with `0 <= y-x && y-x <= 1`

Comment: @Caridorc This is a great solution Carsten. I have posted my own explanation of the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35367835/260584

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful and idiomatic to write your function to take a predicate, instead of writing your split condition into the function itself:

```
splitBy2 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitBy2 ok xs = snd $ f xs [] []
  where f (a:b:xs) acc_list acc_out_lists | ok a b = ...
```